# Duplicates with in a sentence of a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.8

Hi I want to write a code that reads a text file, and identifies the sentences in the file with words that have duplicates within that sentence. I was thinking of putting each sentence of the file in a dictionary and finding which sentences have duplicates. Since I am new to Python, I need some help in writing the code.

This is what I have so far:

```
def Sentences():
    def Strings():
        l = string.split('.')

        for x in range(len(l)):
            print('Sentence', x + 1, ': ', l[x])

        return

    text = open('Rand article.txt', 'r')

    string = text.read()

    Strings()

    return
```

The code above converts files to sentences.

Comment: Can you show your attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and lets start from there.

Comment: I too would use a dictionary to solve the problem.  So it looks like you need to read the file, break it into sentences, break each sentence into words and push the words into a dictionary to spot the duplicates (you could also use a set for that).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a file where each line is a sentence, e.g. "sentences.txt":

```
I contain unique words.
This sentence repeats repeats a word.
```

The strategy could be to split the sentence into its constituent words, then use `set` to find the unique words in the sentence. If the resulting `set` is shorter than the `list` of all words, then you know that the sentence contains at least one duplicated word:

```
sentences_with_dups = []
with open("sentences.txt") as fh:
    for sentence in fh:
        words = sentence.split(" ")
        if len(set(words)) != len(words):
            sentences_with_dups.append(sentence)
```